# sqlite3 adapter error after upgrading rails version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I updated my rails from 3.0.3 to 3.1.1 recently. I've been through all the processes they asked me to do for further dependency installation such as "Development Kit", and I've got it all done all right. Anyway, when I went back to run an application in command prompt (windows), I encountered the problem as below.

```
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/connect
ion_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:71:in `rescue in establish_con
nection': Please install the sqlite3 adapter: `gem install activerecord-sqlite3-
adapter` (RubyGem version error: sqlite3(1.3.3 not ~> 1.3.4) (RuntimeError)
)
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_r
ecord/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:68:in `establish_
connection'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_r
ecord/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:60:in `establish_
connection'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_r
ecord/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:55:in `establish_
connection'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_r
ecord/railtie.rb:69:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_
support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_
support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_
support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `block in run_load_hooks'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_
support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_
support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `run_load_hooks'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_r
ecord/base.rb:2190:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_r
ecord/railtie.rb:34:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/railti
e.rb:178:in `call'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/railti
e.rb:178:in `block in load_console'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/railti
e.rb:178:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/railti
e.rb:178:in `load_console'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/engine
.rb:407:in `block in load_console'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/applic
ation/railties.rb:8:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/applic
ation/railties.rb:8:in `all'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/engine
.rb:407:in `load_console'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/applic
ation.rb:115:in `load_console'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/comman
ds/console.rb:27:in `start'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/comman
ds/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/comman
ds.rb:40:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:57:i
n `require'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:57:i
n `rescue in require'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:i
n `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I have tried to fix the problem by installing the missing sqlite 1.3.3 component, but
the thing seems not to work out fine from me.

Any advice would be really grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't it saying that it needs 1.3.4?

Change sqlite3 in your gemfile to

```
gem "sqlite3", "~> 1.3.4"
```

Then run bundle.